# How do I append a character to the end of a String

Tags: common-lisp

From my understanding Strings are vectors of type character. So far my attempts have been unfruitful

```
(vector-push #\a "Hol")
;; "Hol" Is not of type vector and simple-array
```

Is the literal "Hol" a constant vector in the same manner that '(1 2 3) is not the same as (list 1 2 3)? Should I just create a vector of characters explicitly and add characters to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got the right diagnosis.  It's not even a matter of literal data (e.g., `(list 1 2 3)` vs. `'(1 2 3)`) versus modifiable data, though.  It's whether the vector has a [fill pointer](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fill_p.htm).  The documentation for [`vector-push` and `vector-push-extend`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_vec_ps.htm) say that the *vector* argument is a vector with a fill pointer.  You'll get a similar error with non-literal arrays that don't have a fill pointer, as in:

```
(let ((v (make-array 3)))
  (vector-push nil v))
```

All you need to do is make sure that you create the vector with a fill pointer, and that it big enough to hold the things you push in:

```
(let ((v (make-array 2 :fill-pointer 0)))
  (print v)
  (vector-push 'x v)
  (print v)
  (vector-push 'y v)
  (print v)
  (vector-push 'z v)
  (print v))
```

`vector-push` doesn't adjust the array, so you get not `z` in the vector from the final `vector-push`:

```
#() 
#(X) 
#(X Y) 
#(X Y)
```

If you make the vector adjustable, and use `vector-push-extend`, you can get a bigger array:

```
(let ((v (make-array 2 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0)))
  (print v)
  (vector-push 'x v)
  (print v)
  (vector-push 'y v)
  (print v)
  (vector-push-extend 'z v)
  (print v))

#() 
#(X) 
#(X Y) 
#(X Y Z)
```

Using an element type of `character`, you'll be doing this with strings:

```
(let ((v (make-array 2 :element-type 'character :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0)))
  (print v)
  (vector-push #\x v)
  (print v)
  (vector-push #\y v)
  (print v)
  (vector-push-extend #\z v)
  (print v))

"" 
"x" 
"xy" 
"xyz"
```

Comment: One question, why do you put an @ char as the initial element. (char-code #\@) -> 64 which is the codepoint for the literal @ sign.

Comment: @PuercoPop My first examples included initial elements, so in the interest of changing as little as possible, I used an initial element in the string example.  However, SBCL signals an error if the initial element for a string isn't a character, so I used a character that just so happened to be `#\@`.  However, none of these examples need initial elements, so I've removed them from the examples.